# Modeling the fluid dynamics of semen

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Is there a good model for the fluid dynamics of human ejaculation of semen?

I'm looking to do some sperm motility research in the near future and would like to tinker with a model from a good paper.

Comment: +1. But your question is almost certainly going to be deleted if you don't make this look a little bit less like "spam" or "trolling". What is the goal of this research you're planning to do in the future, and what have you found so far? You do have to show that you've done *some* research or made *some* effort at answering the question before asking here. I would also recommend that you register your account: You are an unregistered user at the moment, which makes your question less likely to get answered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I've specifically been looking over the research out of Tulane's mathematics department, but the papers are now a bit dated -- and it's hard to find another group that does research in this area of Fluids.

Comment: The last "unregistered user" we had got deleted for spam: your question isn't as bad as theirs, but I'd strongly recommend you register, as most people here will be reluctant to interact with a question from someone not registered. I understand that you've been looking over the research in Tulane's mathematics department, but what is the purpose? Is this for an MSc project? PhD project? 4th year undergrad thesis? Just for fun?

Comment: I know the Q is currently closed, but if it helps, here is an out-of-the box project that is on arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00926 . "Projectile Trajectory of Penguin's Faeces and Rectal Pressure Revisited" 
As Nike stated above, it would be helpful if you provide more context, and maybe some key references that show that this is a serious and open question. Maybe even change the title to something like "viscous fuids"? Idk, something that will want people to come and answer...